# Can linux ssh private key files be used unchanged in putty on Windows?

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I have been connecting to my site from a Mac using ssh. My Mac is dead. Now I have my key files but need to use Putty on Windows...

1 - Can I take my id_rsa file and rename it as private.ppk and use it as-is with Putty?

2 - Are there any gotchas? - because the remote server is refusing my keys. :(

Comment: All tickety boo now, thanks to @chris' and @Jander below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use OpenSSH keys directly with PuTTY, but if you have the `puttygen` tool (by the author of PuTTY), you can import them.

For directions, see the following from the PuTTY documentation: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-conversions

Answer (score 4):

No, you need to convert them first using [puttygen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Comment: Thank you! You have saved my bacon. It had been a while since I used putty in anger ...but the anger was coming! :)